# moz selector not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a gallery and it works fine in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox. Even when I try the "-moz" prefix in my CSS it still loads the page with those declarations commented out and unloaded by the browser.

In Chrome & IE it loads properly (4 columns on desktop, 2 on mobile). But in Firefox its just a big "list" of images one after another.

Here is a link to a fiddle with my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/hzLsgh1h/3/

CSS:

```
.container {
  width:90%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;  
}
.row-wrapper-adaptive {
  overflow: hidden;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}    
.col-4-adaptive {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 4;
}    
.col-adaptive {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
img {
  display:block;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;  
}

@media only screen and (max-width:950px) {
  .row-wrapper-adaptive {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .col-4-adaptive {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 15px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, surely I've just overlooked something here!

**EDIT**

Even with no browser prefixes at all the code still won't work in Firefox - here is an updated fiddle with prefixes stripped out.

https://jsfiddle.net/4box1y3b/1/

Hoping to see an example that makes it work in Firefox

Comment: Just use standards and firefox will appreciate it. You are using only propietary sentences. See: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol-1/#the-multi-column-model . You can use `columns` property with two values, or splitted `column-width` and `column-count`. You really don't need more than this.

Comment: And other thing, don't think that only by writing `-moz-` at the start of a property will work on firefox... You need to go to documentation before and ensure that property exists. I recommend only use standards and all will be fine on all browsers

Comment: You don't really need the `-moz-` prefix anymore... anything that's supported by FF will work without it, and anything it doesn't won't work anyway.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=column None of the browsers needs any prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, inside and outside media queries. -moz is not required.
 `.col-4-adaptive {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap:15px;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I made those changes in the fiddle and still no luck? Could you have a go at it and see if it works for you?
https://jsfiddle.net/4box1y3b/4/

Comment: When I look at your new fiddle, I don't see any difference between Mozilla an Chrome. They both change from 2 to 4 columns at 950px. So what goes wrong at your end?

Comment: I see this in Firefox - just one big "list" of them regardless of browser size http://imgur.com/a/XbtPC @MrLister

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 What version of Firefox are you testing against?

Comment: @MrLister it had been 47.0.2 (i dont use it often at all), just ran an update and am now on 53.0 - thinks work perfectly now :) thanks for calling out a simple thing like that. Hadn't even thought of that!

Comment: @MrLister guys like you are so helpful! Thanks for taking the time to answer me back and not just write it off as working

Comment: Check my code completely, you are still using column-count: 4 in the col-4-adaptive class. make it as column-count: 2 inside and also outside the media queries as well.